# No Qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am not able to autowire a bean with it's name using Qualifier annotation

This is for Spring Boot 2.1.4

#### In Project A

```java
@RestController
@ImportResource({"classpath*:config/CrudBeans.xml"})
public class WebCrudController extends BaseWebController 
                               interface RuleEngineExecutorI{

}
```

#### In Project B

```java
@Component("ruleEngineExecutor")
public class RuleEngineRestletExecutor extends WebCrudController  
                                       implements RuleEngineExecutorI {
}
```

#### In project C

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("ruleEngineExecutor")
RuleEngineExecutorI webExecuteController;
```

> Project C contains dependency of Project B and B contains a 
>         dependency of A

#### In project C's application class

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.A","com.B"})
```

I should get a bean generated with RuleEngineRestletExecutor  which I am not getting . Instead I am getting and error as

> No qualifying bean of type 'com.A.RuleEngineExecutorI' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Comment: *I am not able to autowire a bean with it's name using Qualifier annotation* Are you sure that is the case? the Qualifier? Maybe component is not created at all. Try to inject RuleEngineRestletExecutor directy to confirm or rule that out.

Comment: I was ready to answer but realized there are many possibilities for this error. Try one of the following: Move the qualifier class to project A and see if it works. Specify the package on the qualifier name (com.B.RuleEngineExecutor, dont know if it works but who knows...). Add package C to the scanned backages on @SpringBootApplication. See if any of those work.